# How to create string variable from array in Azure LogicApps?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have LogicApp which get HTTP Post from Azure Alerts.
I would like to create "DimensionNames" string variable, which includes all names in array.
DimensionNames value could be "name1,name2, name3, name4".
Finally I would use DimenstionNames string in "call Webhook".

How do it?

Request Body Json in "When a HTTP request is received"

```
{
  "dimensions": {
    "items": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "value": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "name",
        "value"
      ],
      "type": "object"
    },
    "type": "array"
  }
}
```

Comment: That's your schema, can you provide an example of the actual payload you receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using variables and Join action you can convert array to a string variable. I have reproduced from my side and below are steps I followed,

1. Created an alert and configured a HTTP trigger logic app to it.
2. Designer of logic app will be,
   [image]
3. The payload of http request is,

```
{
"dimensions": {
"items": {
"properties": {
"name": {
"type": "string"
},
"value": {
"type": "string"
}
},
"required": [
"name",
"value"
],
"type": "object"
},
"type": "array"
}
}
```

[image]
4. Next taken **Initialize variable action** as shown below,
[image]

5. Taken Join action to divide values from array with comma,
   [image]
6. Next taken another initialize variable action to store value as a string,
   [image]
7. In webhook action the value of string variable is used as body,
   [image]
8. Outputs are shown below,

Http trigger:

[image]

Output of initialize variable,
[image]

Output if Join,

[image]

Output of initialize variable 2,

[image]

Reference [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vP9nn.png)